# Combine bar chart and line chart in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, bar-chart, linechart

I am able to create bar chart and displaying strip line through MS Chart below snap:
[image]

Same chart I am trying to create in C# at run time feel like to export the chart in excel. Can anyone guide me how can draw the Strip line on bar chart OR can combine bar chart line chart so line chart seems displaying the strip line.

Comment: can you first create an excel file with the chart and then use C# only to add data?

Comment: Yes, I am creating at run time. First I have taken a dummy excel file on server then doing all these process.

Comment: so the problem is that you don't know how to manually create in excel the line based on data? just to be sure what the problem is, if you have to add the line with C# or it can be in the dummy excel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible approach is to add a new series like this:

1. add a new series to the bar chart, using 2 cells equal to the value where you want to have vertical line (**x** column in illustration)
2. select the new series bars and change chart type to **X Y (Scatter)** - the one with both markers and lines so you can then select it again
3. edit data range for the new series, so x-values point to your value and y-values to 0 and 1
4. change the right axis to **Minimum: Fixed 0,0**, **Maximum: Fixed 1,0** and change major tick lines and axis labels to **None**
5. remove markers and change line style

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually I am not creating chart manually in excel. Same thing I am trying to create using C# and the same thing I did for column chart and it's working fine. I am drawing the line to show the average for all values using line chart. As you suggested, I will try to implement it using C#. But if you have c# example then it would be appreciable.

Comment: nope,, but i guess C# uses similar COM interface to VBA, so recording a macro in excel should help...

Comment: Just wanted to update you, Just wanted to show average line. So first I created a series with average value then created a linear trend line for this series. So it seems average line. Then finally hide this series. It was workable for me in C#.

Comment: good for you,, it these steps worked for you, please accept the answer :) or add your own answer with what worked and accept that - for future readers..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now accepted and future reader may got bother answer :)